# Property "Craft\SessionRecord.token" is not defined

Tags: admin, error, login, session

I'm trying to log in to the admin area of an local install but all that happens is the page refreshes and nothing happens. Digging deeper I found this in the log:

```
2016/03/09 09:16:38 [error] [exception.CException] exception
'CException' with message 'Property "Craft\SessionRecord.token" is not defined.'
in /craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php:173
```

I've tried re-downloading the app folder from Craft (which updated the install to the latest version fine) and I've also disabled all plugins but the issue persists.

Has anyone else come across this error and know how to solve it? Thank you!

Stack trace:

```
2016/03/09 17:29:36 [error] [exception.CException] exception    'CException' with message 'Property "Craft\SessionRecord.token" is not  defined.' in /path/to/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php:173
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/craft/app/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(162): CComponent->__set('token', 'ea2be7c4a632df0...')
#1 /path/to/craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php(728): CActiveRecord->__set('token', 'ea2be7c4a632df0...')
#2 /path/to/craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php(626): Craft\UserSessionService->storeSessionToken(Object(Craft\UserModel), 'ea2be7c4a632df0...')
#3 /path/to/craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php(549): Craft\UserSessionService->loginByUserId('1', false, true)
#4 /path/to/craft/app/controllers/UsersController.php(66): Craft\UserSessionService->login('impalondon', 'NewPassword', false)
#5 /path/to/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\UsersController->actionLogin()
#6 /path/to/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#7 /path/to/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#8 /path/to/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#9 /path/to/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('login')
#10 /path/to/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(815): CWebApplication->runController('users/login')
#11 /path/to/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(285): Craft\WebApp-  >_processActionRequest()
#12 /path/to/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#13 /path/to/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#14 /path/to/index.php(14): require_once('/Users/alecrits...')
#15 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php/admin/actions/users/login
HTTP_REFERER=http://impalondon.dev/admin/login
```

[image]

Comment: If you enable devMode is there any plugin involved further down in the stack trace maybe?

Comment: Actually sharing the full stack trace would be useful, too.

Comment: @BradBell , sure thing added stack trace

Comment: If you open `craft/app/records/SessionRecord` and find the `defineAttributes` method, is `token` one of the attributes?

Comment: Yes, I got this: `'token' => array(AttributeType::String, 'maxLength' => 100, 'column' => ColumnType::Char, 'required' => true),`

Comment: Well... wtf.  Does the `craft_session` table in the database have a `token` column?

Comment: Yeah it does i've added a screenshot from Sequel Pro, never come across this issue before...

Comment: Hrm... I'm out of ideas. I was going to say if it's on a public site and you don't mind sharing credentials, hit us up at support@craftcms.com, but it looks like its local.  Definitely first time I've seen that behavior.

Comment: Maybe send a database backup to support and will see if we can reproduce it with just that. Probably worth sending your `config/general.php` file along as well.

Comment: Yeah no worries, thanks for your input. I'll try get it onto a staging server to test again and if it's still the same issue I'll throw you guys an email with some credentials :)

Comment: Put it to staging, Craft performed a little update for some reason but now I can log in fine. Not sure what happened or why but the issue is resolved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hah... yay?  Maybe add that as a (not-so-satisfying) official answer I suppose.

Comment: @AlecRitson, have you encountered any shimmering insights that'd allow you to answer this question, or should I just disappear it? I'm glad you've been able to move on, I'm just not sure there's much value left here for future visitors.

Comment: Hey @MattStein I haven't had a chance yet, It's all on git so I'm gonna fetch the latest (from the little update craft did) and then compare to see what's gone on and what's changed to see if it gives a clue and then update this with any answer, so if you could hold fire for a little while that would be grand :)

Comment: Good luck then, @AlecRitson, and thanks for your diligence!